# Is the antecedent of a relative clause always the nearest noun?

Tags: grammar, relative-clauses, clauses

I found this line in a film, The Grand Budapest Hotel.

> There are still faint glimmers of civilization left in this barbaric slaughterhouse that was once known as humanity.

What was once known as humanity? The faint glimmers of civilization or slaughterhouse?

Is the antecedent of a relative clause always the nearest noun?

Comment: It's kinda right there: this slaughterhouse [that] was once known as humanity. The film is satirical in the extreme.

Comment: Not always, but it is in your example, where the antecedent is the nominal "barbaric slaughterhouse".

Comment: There are a lot of similar questions: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/104033/determining-pronoun-antecedents https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/105784/antecedent-of-which-in-a-man-coming-out-of-the-backdoor-of-his-house-which-is https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/476579/restrictive-relative-pronoun-clause-and-antecedent

Comment: No, it can be a whole sentence, JS.